# Mouse copy/paste in gnu screen stopped working

Tags: mouse, emacs, gnu-screen, copy-paste

I'm working over ssh on a linux machine (RHEL 6.8) from MacOS (Yosemite) through iTerm2 (3.0.20161031-nightly).  On the remote server, I work in screens (Screen version 4.00.03).

*Edit: everything below holds true for highlighting text and trying CMD+C, CMD+V for copy/paste*

The remote server was rebooted for standard security update reasons the other day.  Ever since, copy-paste in the remote screens is all messed up and I have no idea what's going wrong.

If I open up a fresh iTerm2 session on my laptop, I can highlight copy and middle-click paste text with my mouse as usual.

If I ssh into the remote machine and try to copy/paste something from the initial command line prompt, everything works.

If I reconnect to my screen and start a new sub-screen and try to copy/paste something, everything works.

If I log into a similar remote server with a similar setup, go into emacs -nw in a screen on *that* machine and try to copy/paste, everything works.

However, when I log into this server and connected to a screen running, say ipython or emacs (in terminal mode), which is how I always work, the mouse highlight / middle click paste scheme goes haywire.  Until this week, it worked normally.

From within my reconnected screen (I use sub-screens that I flip back and forth between):

- In emacs highlighting and middle-clicking does nothing (at the moment, though I think before it was behaving the same as below.  *Edit: it does.  The behavior is the same in ipython and emacs, and are apparently tied together*).
- In e.g. ipython, if I highlight some text and then middle-click, what's pasted is actually the text from some number of lines (the exact number changes) below what's highlighted, e.g.:

  ```
  ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
  %quickref -> Quick reference.
  help      -> Python's own help system.
  object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
  ```

if I highlight "Introduction and overview" and middle-click on the python command line, what's pasted is "Details about 'object', u"

This all worked normally until this week; I might have tweaked some settings in e.g. emacs awhile back to make everything work with the mouse.  As far as I know, nothing on my machine has changed.  But my understanding of the copy-paste dynamic here is that it would be all my system and not the remote server.  But I only see the problem within screens on this remote server.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I believe it is related to the fact that we are using screen. I removed the lines relating to mousetrack from my .screenrc and regained access to copy/pasting. I am not sure if mousetrack and mouse-based copy/paste can be made to work together. I am on Windows 8.1 with Cygwin logging into Centos machines.

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue, for me it was `mousetrack` option that was confusing me in my `~/.screenrc`.

**You can turn mousetrack off with**:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> and `:mousetrack off`

You can check mousetrack status from active screen with:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> and `:mousetrack`

Turning mousetrack off should convert the mouse behavior to the default for non mouse enabled programs (marking and pasting as expected).

Comment: Worked for me via putty screen, im going to look to see if i have something overridden in my .screenrc, or add it if not.  not sure why it started, maybe  because its a different environment that i pulled my screenrc from.